# Regional decimal separator and ADODB prepared SQL requests for MS-Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, adodb

Please consider this VBA macro (I run it from excel to update the content of a MS-Access Table) :

```
Dim connect As ADODB.Connection
Dim Param As ADODB.Parameter
Dim Command As ADODB.Command

Set Param = New ADODB.Parameter

Param.Type = adNumeric
Param.Value = 3.02

Param.Precision = 4
Param.NumericScale = 2

Set Command = New ADODB.Command

Command.CommandText = "UPDATE MyTable SET DecimalField = ? WHERE ID = 138721"
Command.Prepared = True

Command.Parameters.Append Param

Set connect = New ADODB.Connection
connect.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
connect.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & DB_Test & ";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;Persist Security Info=False;"
connect.Open

Command.ActiveConnection = connect

Command.execute
```

It works perfectly so long the system decimal separator is `.`

If I change the system regional settings to use `,` as decimal separator, the last macro line throws this error :

> The decimal field's precission is too small to accept the numeric you
>   attempted to add

I can use `.` or `,` as decimal separator, VBA is always converting it in Variant/Decimal :

[image: Param content]

Then, I assume ADODB is not enable to pass a decimal to the MS-Access database when the system decimal separator is not `.`.

Is there a way to get it working with prepared statements ?

Comment: My guess is, only by converting each number to a string and changing all `,`s to `.`s.

Comment: The string representation of a number should have no bearing on any of this. What's the server-side definition of the numeric/decimal field?

Comment: @wazz Setting `Param.Value = "3.02"` does the same, and the property is auto-converted in Variant/Decimal

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon : Data type: Number, Field Size: Decimal, Format: General Number, Precision: 4, Scale 2, Decimal Places : Auto, other options are empty. I also tried to use adDecimal instead of adNumeric for the type of the parameter, it doesn't help.

Comment: i meant to also convert it back to numeric, but i guess it's irrelevant.

Comment: Does it work using DAO parameterized query? It might be one of the gaps in ADODB provider.

Comment: If it's a decimal, you should user `adDecimal`, not `adNumeric` for the parameter. Else you will have typecasting and trouble. Also try omitting the precision + scale stuff, that's generally not needed.

Comment: Can you specify the locale in the connection string? For example, France has [locale ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/intl/language-identifier-constants-and-strings) 1036 (= &H080C) so the connection string would be `"Data Source=" & DB_Test & ";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;Persist Security Info=False;Locale Identifier=1036;"`

Comment: @this I don't know and I want to achieve this with ADODB

Comment: @ErikA `adDecimal` was one of the first things I tried. It does not help, adDecimal and adNumeric are "basically" the same with a MS-Access database. I know Precision and NumericScale are not needed, but I wanted to avoid comments like "can you try to add Precision ad Numeric Scale ?" ;)

Comment: @barrowc Good idea. I was searching something like that. But it does not work, even with germany locale ID (1031) which I know it is with comma. I was wondering if I can find a documentation about the connection string optional parameters ? May be there is something like `"Decimal separator=,;"`

Comment: I also tested with en-US locale ID (1033). It doest not help